# Issue with connecting the mongo cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have an error:  querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.12345  connecting to cluster in Mongo compass and my password contains '@'. Any suggestions to fix it??

Comment: Did you try the "Fill in connection fields individually" option in Compass?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself. 
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 
read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.